# Foreground color not working in buttonstyle

Tags: flutter

I have a button with the foreground colour set to green  but it still display the text in white, it's probably a mistake from my part, please help. Here is my code

```
ButtonStyle skipStyle() {
    return ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(5),
          ),
          side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: kSecondaryColor )
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(kSkipButtonTextStyle),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried making a small example using the same ButtonStyle and got result as expected. What is ```kSkipButtonTextStyle``` in  ```textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(kSkipButtonTextStyle)``` ? It shouldn't affect the colour of the text (see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/textStyle.html)) but it doesn't hurt to see.

Comment: I didn't specify any color in ```kSkipButtonTextStyle```, but i restarted my editor and it works well now, thank you